# Facebook single sign on with ios 6.0 and storyboard

Tags: facebook, authentication, ios6, storyboard, single-sign-on

I have used following tutorial to use the new 6.0 Facebook integration for signing in. 
[iOS 6 Tutorial: Integrating Facebook into Your Applications](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/eric-stroh/ios-6-tutorial-integrating-facebook-your-applications)

Here I dont need the Facebook SDK just new social framework from apple and it works well.

My question is how do I structure this single sign on in a storyboard? 
My log in view should, after successful validation, redirect the user to next view and never really appear again.

I've been looking at a prepare for seque solution but not sure how I capture the users log in status and how that is also checked next time the user opens the application.

When log in button is pressed following function is triggered:

```
- (IBAction)advancedButtonPressed:(id)sender {

self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

NSString *key = @"270430619733847";
NSDictionary *dictFB = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:key,ACFacebookAppIdKey,@[@"email"],ACFacebookPermissionsKey, nil];


[self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFB completion:

 ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
     if (granted) {
         NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];

         //it will always be the last object with single sign on
         self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
         NSLog(@"facebook account =%@",self.facebookAccount);
         [self get];

     } else {
         //Fail gracefully...
         NSLog(@"error getting permission %@",e);

     }
 }];
```

The get method is:

```
-(void)get
```

{

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                  URL:requestURL
                                           parameters:nil];
request.account = self.facebookAccount;

[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                     NSHTTPURLResponse *response,
                                     NSError *error) {

    if(!error)
    {
        list =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Dictionary contains: %@", list );
        if([list objectForKey:@"error"]!=nil)
        {
            [self attemptRenewCredentials];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            nameLabel.text = [list objectForKey:@"username"];
        });
    }
    else{
        //handle error gracefully
        NSLog(@"error from get%@",error);
        //attempt to revalidate credentials
    }

}];
```